# Can I get a keystroke combination to enter $" for me?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019:

The problem I find with dollar-quoted strings is that I need to use one hand to hold the shift key for the dollar sign and the other hand to hold the shift key for the double quote. I would like to assign a single keystroke combination (preferably Ctrl-") to type those two characters. But for some reason I will never understand, Microsoft killed off keystroke macros in VS 2012. I know there are extensions I can download that will let me create macros, but I'm curious if there's a way to do this in unextended VS 2019 (and earlier versions too, if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ASCII chars such as: Alt-36 Alt-34

Comment: How would  use them?  How would I assign them to a keystroke combination?

Comment: You press and hold down the Alt key and press 3 then 6 and let up on the Alt key. Then press and hold the Alt key and press 3 then 4. It will produce $"

Comment: Ah.  I see.  That's a little better, but I still want a single combination keystroke.